# Cannot connect to mongo db which lives inside docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a Node JS demo app which I want to connect to a Mongo database. My code is on a server which doesn't support Mongo, so I try to run it from a docker container. When I run the app, I get some error regarding the connection to the db:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo mongo:27017]`

The container with the database is up and running:

```
[root@xxxxxx docker-node-mongo]# docker run -d -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 --name mongodb mongo:4.0.4^C0.0:27017-27019->27017-27019/tcp   mongodb


[root@xxxxxx docker-node-mongo]# [root@vps12219000 docker-node-mongo]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              
PORTS                                  NAMES
ccdf49525782        mongo:4.0.4         "docker-entrypoint.s   26 minutes ago      Up 26 
minutes       0.0.0.0:27017-27019->27017-27019/tcp   mongodb
```

and I am connecting to the DB like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB_URI = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/toDoApp';

mongoose.connect(DB_URI).then(() => {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + PORT);
  app.listen(PORT);
});
```

Can someone please advise what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Note: I want to run only the DB inside a container, but not the Node part.

Comment: If the application is running outside Docker, it needs to use the host's IP address (or 127.0.0.1, if the application and container are on the same host) and the `docker run -p` published port; so `localhost:27017` most likely.

Comment: can you please add the log of the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze - `localhost:27017` did the trick. Many thanks!